# why my d3 selection index not working

Tags: d3.js, indexing, selection

here is code fragment from label-drawing function

```
var legend = d3.select("." + to_chart)
    .append("g")
    .selectAll("g")
        .data(data)
            .enter().append("rect")
            .attr("width", 20)
            .attr("height", 20)
            .attr("x", 20)
            .attr("y", 20)
            .attr("transform", function(d, i){return "translate(0," + i * 30 + ")";})
            .attr("style", "stroke: #000; stroke-width: 1px")
            .attr("fill", function(d, i) { return color(i); });
var legend = d3.select("." + to_chart)
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "t")
    .selectAll(".t")
        .data(data)
            .enter().append("text")
                    .attr("x", function(data, i){return i;})
                    .attr("y", 20)
                    .text(function(i){if (i = 0){
                        return "eff";
                    } else if (i = 1) {
                        return "non-eff";
                    }
                    ;});
```

why .attr("x", function(data, i){return i;}) is working, but 
.text section not? it always get the '1' value.

Comment: You need to pass the value AND index parameters to the function: `function(d,i) ...`. The first parameter is the value and the second is the index...if you only pass one parameter, no matter if you call it d or i, the value is what is returned.

Comment: okay, I passed it early, but in function i always equals to 1, but I expect 0 and 1

Comment: of course, it returns 0 and 1 on matching iterations. It's very strange that two strings down it is not working.

Comment: If you want to use the index in the .text() call, then the call must be `text(function(d,i) {...})`, where d is the value and i is the index. Right now it is `text(function(i){...}`, so i represents the value.

Comment: it works if I just return the value. but I want to return text depends on index, that I have to specify.
now it .text(function(d, i){if ... ;});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I put an example down...besides the problem I mentioned with the `function(d,i){...}`, your comparison operator was wrong...you want to use `===` or `==` instead of `=`. So here is the deal:

```
var data = ["mary","goes"]

var legend = d3.select("body").append("svg").append("g")
    .attr("class", "t")
    .selectAll(".t")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
  .append("text")
    .attr("x", function(d, i){return i * 30;})
    .attr("y", 20)
    .text(function(d,i){
        if (i === 0){
            return "eff";
        } else if (i === 1) {
            return "non-eff";
        }
    ;});
```

This results in:

eff  non-eff

Comment: Thank you :) This re-enforces a good discipline...I should put it down as complete an example as possible to surface any surprises.

Comment: And I am speaking from the perspective of the person trying to answer the question.

Comment: It is not necessary. Once I was able to isolate the main piece as a complete example, I could see the problem clearly. Thanks!